# How to save the image?

Tags: android, save, picasso

I am using Picasso to fetch image and I just want to save the image.Below code is not working for me to save the image.

```
public class DownloadImage extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mindmaps);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);


    Picasso.with(this)
            .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
            .into(imageView);
    final Button btntakephoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    btntakephoto.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
}


    public void onClick(View v){
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Drawable image = imageView.getDrawable();
        if (image != null && image instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image;
            Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
            try {
                File file = new File("path where you want to save");
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                stream.flush();
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }
```

On pressing the save button image should be saved in the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Make your DownloadImage class implement View.OnClickListener interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

call this method from button click:

```
private void saveImage() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Drawable image = imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), image);
        OutputStream out = null;
        String fileName = "MyImage.jpg";
        String mPath = "";
        try {
            out = mActivity.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            File f = mActivity.getFileStreamPath(fileName);

            mPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Logger.logger("URI :" + mPath);

    }
```